# How to convert a batch file to XML file

Tags: xml, powershell, batch-file, msbuild-4.0

I am having a file where Xcopy commands were written. Now i need to move them to xml file format so that i can execute with them in Msbuild.

Following are my file contents

```
xcopy File1 Destinationfolder1
Xcopy File2 DestinationFolder2
Xcopy File3 DestinationFolder1
```

I would like to make it as xml file as follows

```
<Xcopy include="File1">
<Destination> DestinationFolder1 </Destination>
</Xcopy>

<Xcopy Include="File2">
<Destination> DestinationFolder2 </Destination>
</Xcopy>

and so on..
```

Is there any powershell script or some other easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
clear
$res = Get-Content c:\PST\1.txt

$xml = [xml] "<root namespace=`"namespace`"></root>"
foreach($line in $res)
{
# If words are separated by more than one whitespace
$line=$line -replace '\s+', ' ' 
$values = $line.Split(" ")
$insert = [xml] [string]::Format("<Xcopy include=`"{0}`"> <Destination>{1}</Destination> </Xcopy>", $values[1], $values[2])
$importNode = $xml.ImportNode($insert.DocumentElement, $true) 
$xml.root.AppendChild($importNode) |Out-Null
}
$xml.Save("c:\PST\result.xml")
```

It is working, but I'm pretty sure PowerShell gurus can make it much simpler

Comment: Buddy , It's a great help. Output xml comes in single line. how to add newline between each nodes ? . Sorry i have started powershell recently , so i am not able to fix by myself

Comment: All the <Xcopy> elements are in single lines. After each <xcopy> how to add newline.

Comment: Thanks buddy . I have accepted it as answer. So Instead outerxml if we use save ,it will have space between elements .. huh?

Answer (score 2):

The following cmd batch file gives exactly the output you are looking for:

```
@echo off
rem Syntax: conv inputfile resultfile
set input=%1
set result=%2
copy nul %result%
for /F "tokens=2,3*" %%G in (%input%) do (
  echo ^<Xcopy include="%%G"^> >> %result%
  echo ^<Destination^> %%H ^</Destination^> >> %result%
  echo ^</Xcopy^> >> %result%
  echo. >> %result%
)
```

Comment: Dude, It always produce empty files. I have copied your code in a batch file ( "conv.bat"). And i am calling it like: conv Sourcefile.txt destinationfile.xml. But it fails any typo error in your script or some thing?

Comment: Just done the same thing: copy the code, save it to conv.bat, copy your input data in a text file, and run. It works ok on xp and w7. Perhaps comment the line `@echo off` and see what happens.

Comment: I am sorry. From now it would be debugging by simplifying the code. For instance, replace all the loop with: `for /F %%G in (%input%) do echo %%G` .